# How to use linkRadial to draw a link between two points?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I need to manually draw some links between points on a circle and points clustered in the centre of said circle. I have the x,y pairs for the source and target points, but I don't want a simple straight line between them; I want a curved line (similar to the links that are found in tree diagrams). I could use `linkHorizontal` or `linkVertical` but their tangents are constant; I want to use `linkRadial` and have the tangent be the radial line at that particular arc point (the degree of which I also have).

I don't understand the `linkRadial` API though; it wants an angle and a radius, not an x or y point. How do I convert my two x,y pairs (and the radial line angle) into the angle and radius this is expecting?

Answer (score 6):

Since you have a data array with the `x` and `y` positions (*"I have the x,y pairs for the source and target points"*), you'll have to convert them to `angle` and `radius`. Let's see how to do it.

Firstly, let's see an example with fixed coordinates. For instance, suppose you have this data array, with the `x` and `y` positions:

```
var data = [{
    source: {y: 150,x: 75
    },
    target: {y: 300,x: 0
    }
}, {
    source: {y: 150,x: 75
    },
    target: {y: 0,x: 0
    }
}, {
    source: {y: 150,x: 75
    },
    target: {y: 150,x: 150
    }
}, ];
```

Using this link generator...

```
var link = d3.linkHorizontal()
    .x(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    })
    .y(function(d) {
        return d.x;
    });
```

... you'll have a chart like this:

```js
var data = [{
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 300,
    x: 0
  }
}, {
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 0,
    x: 0
  }
}, {
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 150,
    x: 150
  }
}, ];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var link = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  });

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("d", link);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

How can we convert this to a data set that can be used with `d3.linkRadial()`?

One option is iterating with each object, using basic trigonometry to populate the `angle` and `radius` properties:

```
var radialData = data.map(function(d) {
    return {
        source: {
            x: 0,
            y: 0
        },
        target: {
            x: Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x) - Math.PI,
            y: Math.sqrt((d.target.x - d.source.x) * (d.target.x - d.source.x) + (d.target.y - d.source.y) * (d.target.y - d.source.y))
        }
    };
});
```

Then, using this link generator:

```
var linkRadial = d3.linkRadial()
    .angle(function(d) {
        console.log(d)
        return d.x;
    })
    .radius(function(d) {
        return d.y;
    });
```

We'll have this:

```js
var data = [{
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 300,
    x: 0
  }
}, {
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 0,
    x: 0
  }
}, {
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 150,
    x: 150
  }
}, ];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var radialData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    source: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    target: {
      x: Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x) - Math.PI,
      y: Math.sqrt((d.target.x - d.source.x) * (d.target.x - d.source.x) + (d.target.y - d.source.y) * (d.target.y - d.source.y))
    }
  };
});

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150,75)")

var linkRadial = d3.linkRadial()
  .angle(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .radius(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

g.selectAll(null)
  .data(radialData)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", linkRadial);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```

Now both generators together, for comparison:

```js
var data = [{
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 300,
    x: 0
  }
}, {
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 0,
    x: 0
  }
}, {
  source: {
    y: 150,
    x: 75
  },
  target: {
    y: 150,
    x: 150
  }
}, ];

var svg = d3.select("svg");

var link = d3.linkHorizontal()
  .x(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  });

svg.selectAll(null)
  .data(data)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "blue")
  .attr("d", link);

var radialData = data.map(function(d) {
  return {
    source: {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    },
    target: {
      x: Math.atan2(d.target.y - d.source.y, d.target.x - d.source.x) - Math.PI,
      y: Math.sqrt((d.target.x - d.source.x) * (d.target.x - d.source.x) + (d.target.y - d.source.y) * (d.target.y - d.source.y))
    }
  };
});

var g = svg.append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(150,75)")

var linkRadial = d3.linkRadial()
  .angle(function(d) {
    return d.x;
  })
  .radius(function(d) {
    return d.y;
  });

g.selectAll(null)
  .data(radialData)
  .enter()
  .append("path")
  .attr("fill", "none")
  .attr("stroke", "red")
  .attr("d", linkRadial);
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.js"></script>
<svg></svg>
```